# Mamp Pro не видит изменение в коде

Tags: mamp

Подскажите, пожалуйста, буквально вчера нареканий на было а сегодня появилась бажина..

Запускаю сервер на Mamp pro, создал функцию и передаю в нее значение, так вот, при сохранении документа и обновлении страницы, значение не отображается, а после перезагрузки Mamp отображает.. то есть сервер видит изменение только после перезагрузки, где копать?  Спасибо